# Swap genders on this page (code-golf)

Tags: code-golf

Yesterday at work, the Google Doodle convinced me to share my rather long gender swap script here, but the code-golf criteria of [the question i asked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/23348/swap-genders-in-any-english-text/23349) were not clear. As my question still got downvoted after giving examples, i changed the tag to popularity-contest, as suggested before i clarified it.

Here's a more golfy version:

The UN theme for [International Women's Day](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=International_Women%27s_Day&oldid=598677309) 2014 is "Equality for Women is Progress for All".

In the interest of gender equality, write a program that correctly changes that Wikipedia page from a female to a male perspective. Names and anatomical details may be left unchanged. It should not change who is being referred to.

Example:

Before:

> He said she took her girlish books on Feminism with her.

After:

> She said he took his boyish books on Masculism with him.

All gendered pronouns and nouns, as well as all adjectival forms of such words, must be changed in the visible English text.

The shortest code that fully transforms the linked version of the IWD Wikipedia page according to the stated rules, wins.

Comment: Could still do with some scoping if you want it to be a code-golf. Must proper names be changed? Must words in URLs be changed? Should herstory become history, and vice versa?  Historian/herstorian? I can guess at your intent, but to make it objective it is best to spell out the tasks that must be done. "Adjectives e.g. boyish and girlish - MUST CONVERT, Proper names - DO NOT CONVERT, etc." In essence, we need to know *how* you will determine the page is "correctly" changed.

Comment: @JonathanVanMatre Please read carefully: "Names and anatomical details may be left unchanged."

Comment: Apologies for overlooking that sentence, but setting that example aside the point is the same: it is best to spell out what must be done. A single sentence that says something to the effect of "All gendered pronouns and nouns, as well as all adjectival forms of such words, must be changed." would suffice.

Comment: I added the proposed sentence and am getting downvoted without comment. [On meta](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1222/4999) my original question only got an upvote. WTF.

Comment: 5 hours in the sandbox on a weekend is a long way short of granting a reasonable expectation that more than a couple of people have seen it. There's no point putting something in the sandbox unless you're going to leave it there for two days or more. And recently people seem too eager to upvote in the sandbox: in the past couple of weeks I've seen people upvote things which then needed to go through three or four edits before becoming truly ready to post. This could still be improved by making explicit that it's a particular *version* of the page which needs changing, so it's a static target.

Comment: (Although even then it's not going to be a very good question: it's basically "work out what the altered text should be (the hardest part), and then find a minimum set of substitutions and a language which has a compact syntax for mass substitutions").

Comment: @PeterTaylor Again, please don't project. I linked to a static Wikipedia version and the sandbox didn't specify vote or time limits. As it was upvoted without comment like the 20+ hour old answers, i assumed it was ready.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Also, the hard part is to minimize the amount of code needed. Else one might easily do it manually and simply replace the whole page content.

Comment: "*Again, please don't project*"??! I'm not sure either what you think I'm projecting or when you think you've previously asked me not to.

Comment: Sorry, i meant being unclear in general, like the first comment.

Comment: Based on what @Peter said, and based on how the previous version of your question went, and based on the lack of any answers other than your own after nearly 2 weeks, I'm inclined to close this question.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young I've restated the objective primary winning criterion at the end of the question.

Comment: @CeesTimmerman Very well.

Comment: What are the terms we need to replace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**JavaScript, 707 bytes (680 in web console)**

```js
javascript:(function(){l=function(s){return s.toLowerCase()};b=document.body;t=b.innerHTML;s="Actress;Actor;Daughters;Sons;Feminine;Masculine;Feminism;Masculism;Feminist;Masculist;Femininity;Masculinity;Mother;Father;Mothers;Fathers;Motherland;Fatherland;Motherhood;Fatherhood;Woman;Man;Female;Male;Females;Males;Girl;Boy;Girls;Boys;Girlfriends;Boyfriends;Grandmothers;Grandfathers;Her;His;She;He;Sister;Brother;Wives;Husbands;WomenWatch;MenWatch;Women;Men;Womensday;Mensday;Internationalwomensday;Internationalmensday;IWD;IMD";a=s.split(';');c=t.split(/\b/);d={};for(i=0;i<a.length;i+=2){x=a[i];y=a[i+1];d[x]=y;d[y]=x;d[l(x)]=l(y);d[l(y)]=l(x)}t='';for(i=0;i<c.length;++i)t+=d[c[i]]||c[i];b.innerHTML=t})()
```

This is a bookmarklet/favelet; set as URL of a bookmark/favorite and click to transform the loaded webpage.

Comment: I guess it simply can't get much shorter than that.

Comment: Hi, I tried it out and it is super awesome, but not all pronouns are swapped. I tried it on a random Wikipedia page and the pronoun _him_ was not swapped, for example. [it was this Wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mukherjee-Samarth_family) But it's nice to have a gender-swap bookmark anyway. :)

Comment: @linse, thanks, but this code-golf challenge is about transforming [this specific page](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=International_Women%27s_Day&oldid=598677309). [Here was](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/23349/4999) a more generic popularity-contest [answer](http://ceestimmerman.blogspot.nl/2014/03/genderswap-any-webpage.html), but that question was deleted for unclear reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Not a completely worked out answer, but Cees' substitution solution reminded me of the str_replace syntax in PHP:

```
$body = file_get_contents($url);
$body = str_replace(
  array("Actress", "Daughters", "Feminine", "Feminism", "Feminist", "Femininity", "Mother", "Mothers", "Motherland", "Motherhood", "Woman", "Female", "Females", "Girl", "Girls", "Girlfriends", "Grandmothers", "Her", "She", "Sister", "Wives", "WomenWatch", "Women", "Womensday", "Internationalwomensday", "IWD"),
  array("Actor", "Sons", "Masculine", "Masculism", "Masculist", "Masculinity", "Father", "Fathers", "Fatherland", "Fatherhood", "Man", "Male", "Males", "Boy", "Boys", "Boyfriends", "Grandfathers", "His", "He", "Brother", "Husbands", "MenWatch", "Men", "Mensday", "Internationalmensday", "IMD"),
  $body);
```

You can shorten this by putting everything into one string, e.g.

```
str_replace( 
  split(';', "Actor;Sons;Masculine;Masculism;Masculist;Masculinity;Father;Fathers;Fatherland;Fatherhood;Man;Male;Males;Boy;Boys;Boyfriends;Grandfathers;His;He;Brother;Husbands;MenWatch;Men;Mensday;Internationalmensday;IMD"), 
   ....
```

but that only makes it marginally better. I'll leave it up to someone to come up with the creative solution.